# make the center of the beautiful spinner transparent

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is one of the best loaders on the net:

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: white;
}

.container{
  positition: relative;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.container .loader{
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #424242;
  animation: animate 1s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes animate{
  0%{
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100%{
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

.container .loader::before{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, transparent, dodgerblue);
  background-size: 100px 180px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border-top-left-radius: 100px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 100px;
}

.container .loader::after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: #00B0FF;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 10;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #00B0FF,
              0 0 20px #00B0FF,
              0 0 30px #00B0FF,
              0 0 40px #00B0FF,
              0 0 50px #00B0FF,
              0 0 60px #00B0FF,
              0 0 70px #00B0FF,
              0 0 80px #00B0FF,
              0 0 90px #00B0FF,
              0 0 100px #00B0FF;
}

.container .loader span{
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #212121;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="loader">
    <span></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to modify the code or find a solution to get ride of the black background in the center and make it transparent while the spinner remain intact but when I remove the background color from `container .loader span` the spinner ruins completely. is there any solution to have the same spinning effect with transparent center?

Comment: not directly. The `#212121` background color is hiding the actual animated content. What you could try is to insert the same background element instead that is use below the spinner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply a mask to the before element like below

```
 mask: radial-gradient(farthest-side at right, transparent calc(100% - 10px), #fff 0);
```

This will keep only the border visible and you can get rid of all the backgrounds

```css
body{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin:0;
  background:linear-gradient(to right,grey,transparent);
}
.loader{
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: animate 1s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes animate{
  100%{
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

.loader::before{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, transparent, dodgerblue) no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 80%;
  border-radius: 100px 0 0 100px;
  -webkit-mask: radial-gradient(farthest-side at right, transparent calc(100% - 10px), #fff 0);
}


.loader::after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 10;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #00B0FF,
              0 0 20px #00B0FF,
              0 0 30px #00B0FF,
              0 0 40px #00B0FF,
              0 0 50px #00B0FF,
              0 0 60px #00B0FF,
              0 0 70px #00B0FF,
              0 0 80px #00B0FF,
              0 0 90px #00B0FF,
              0 0 100px #00B0FF;
}
```

```html
<div class="loader"></div>
```

Or like below to keep the circular border:

```css
body{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin:0;
  background:linear-gradient(to right,grey,transparent);
}
.loader{
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: animate 1s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes animate{
  100%{
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

.loader::before{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, transparent, dodgerblue) no-repeat lightgrey;
  background-size: 50% 80%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-mask: radial-gradient(farthest-side, transparent calc(100% - 10px), #fff 0);
}


.loader::after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 10;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #00B0FF,
              0 0 20px #00B0FF,
              0 0 30px #00B0FF,
              0 0 40px #00B0FF,
              0 0 50px #00B0FF,
              0 0 60px #00B0FF,
              0 0 70px #00B0FF,
              0 0 80px #00B0FF,
              0 0 90px #00B0FF,
              0 0 100px #00B0FF;
}
```

```html
<div class="loader"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change both the background colours to a whiter shade in `.container .loader` and `.container .loader span`.

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: white;
}

.container{
  positition: relative;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.container .loader{
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #DBDBDB;
  animation: animate 1s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes animate{
  0%{
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100%{
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

.container .loader::before{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, transparent, dodgerblue);
  background-size: 100px 180px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border-top-left-radius: 100px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 100px;
}

.container .loader::after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: #00B0FF;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 10;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #00B0FF,
              0 0 20px #00B0FF,
              0 0 30px #00B0FF,
              0 0 40px #00B0FF,
              0 0 50px #00B0FF,
              0 0 60px #00B0FF,
              0 0 70px #00B0FF,
              0 0 80px #00B0FF,
              0 0 90px #00B0FF,
              0 0 100px #00B0FF;
}

.container .loader span{
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #FEFEFE;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="loader">
    <span></span>
  </div>
</div>
```